# Blur viewcontroller darkens after presenting

Tags: ios, objective-c

After I push my view controller as such:

```
self.takeoverViewController = [[NoNetworkViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NoNetworkViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.takeoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

    //find topmost VC and put inside a nav controller
    UIViewController *topViewController = [self getTopMostViewController];

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.takeoverViewController];

    //present the nav controller
    [topViewController presentViewController:nav animated:true completion:^{

    }];
```

The blurview darkens. That is, I see the light blur for an instant, then everything goes darker. Here is how I set up the blurview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self blurBackground];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //hide nav bar
    self.originalNavigationBarState = self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    //show nav bar
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = self.originalNavigationBarState;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UI Utils
- (void)blurBackground {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIBlurEffect *effect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
    UIVisualEffectView *blurView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:effect];
    blurView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view insertSubview:blurView atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: It looks like setting self.view.backgroundColor to whiteColor rather than clearColor may fix your issue.

Comment: If I set it to white, then I won't be able to see the view controller behind it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. There is an UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight that does seem to alleviate your issue slightly but the dimming/darkening effect is still present. It seems that this dimming/darkening effect is the desired outcome of using this class. You may need to write your own to achieve the desired results. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBlurEffect_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBlurEffectStyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [self blurBackground];
//hide nav bar
self.originalNavigationBarState = self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

 }
```

Move [self blurBackground]; in viewWillAppear